# Neovim is not finding a module in ~/.config/nvim

Tags: neovim

I want to use lazy nvim, but whenever I run the command *nvim* it throws an error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ~/.config/nvim/init.lua:2: module 'lua.lazy' not found:
no file '~/.config/nvim/lua/lazy.lua'
```

In my `init.lua`:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';~/.config/nvim/?.lua'
require("lua.lazy")
```

And in `~/.config/nvim/lua/lazy.lua`:

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)
```

I am still able to use NeoVim, but not lazy nvim.
I am using NVIM 0.9.5 and LuaJIT 2.1.1692716794

I have tried with changing the file permissions of lazy.lua, restarting NeoVim and deleting its cache, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You have done an error with `require`: no need to prefix path via `lua` => `require("lazy")`

See https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html#lua-guide-modules for explanations about path to load Lua modules with Neovim.